# Make a request to a specific instance in heroku cloud

Tags: heroku

Some cloud provider services allow to make a request to a specific instance. Is this possible to do in heroku? Looking at the docs i cant see any header to achieve this.

Comment: Dynos are meant to be [disposable](https://12factor.net/disposability) and [interchangeable](https://12factor.net/processes). Why would you want to send  a request to a specific one?

Comment: i am trying to debug a memory issue on the service. and i dont particularly like the method they chose (inspect + remote debugging). i wanted to grab to heaps from the same instance... some cloud services allow this for debugging purposes.

Comment: You're trying to connect interactively (e.g. via SSH) to a running dyno? That's different from "making a request". I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "make a request" you mean an HTTP request, no, this is not possible. [Heroku's routers distribute HTTP traffic between dynos randomly](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#request-distribution):

> Routers use a random selection algorithm for balancing HTTP requests across web dynos. In cases where there are a large number of dynos, the algorithm may optionally bias its selection towards dynos resident in the same AWS availability zone as the router making the selection.

However, if you mean "connect via SSH", you can use [`heroku ps:exec`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec#getting-started):

> Heroku Exec is a feature for creating secure TCP and SSH tunnels into a dyno. It allows for SSH sessions, port forwarding, remote debugging, and inspection with popular Java diagnostic tools.

> By default, Heroku Exec connects to your `web.1` dyno, but you can optionally specify a dyno:
>
> ```
> heroku ps:exec --dyno=web.2
> Establishing credentials... done
> Connecting to web.2 on ⬢ your-app...
> ~ $
> ```